# Star Wars Battlefront 2 Load-Up Error

Tags: directx-9, star-wars-battlefront-2

I just bought Battlefront 2 (good ol' nostalgia) and noticed that when I tried to play it through steam I got an error when loading up. The error is as follows:

> Cannot create Direct3D device! Error: 0x8876086a

Seeing as support for this game is completely gone, I was wondering if anyone else has fixed this problem. My PC specs are:

- AMD A10-6800K APU
- AMD 8760D GPU (Intergrated)
- 8 gB of DDR3 Ram (don't think this is the problem though)

I've reinstalled DirectX probably 10 times, and done everything possible to play this game, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you install DirectX from the BF2 location? DirectX is very picky about that. It should either be on the disc or in the folder when installed.

Comment: I just saw a video about fixing the same error for Left4Dead 2 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xV1o5iQ-6nM). The gist is that the resolution was set manually using command line options. To set them right-click the game in steam, go to properties -> Launch options. For Battlefront 2 the resolution command seems to be `-resolution W H`, where `W` and `H` are your screen width and height, respectively, e.g. `-resolution 1920 1080`. Give it a try and if it works, I'll make it into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's very likely a video driver problem. Try installing the latest drivers for your APU/GPU.

Comment: Sweet! It was either that or compatibility mode because it works now! Thanks!